# Hiding/unhiding list elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a "filterable" list of items.  The user should be able to click on a list element (the parent), which would hide all other parent elements and show the "children".

An example of the html is:

```
<ul class='parent_list'>
    <li>Parent 1</li>
        <ul class='child_list'>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent 2</li>
        <ul class='child_list hidden'>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$('.parent_list li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass('hidden');
    $(this).children().removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Of course, you can probably tell by the javascript that I don't have too much experience with things like this.  I've tried searching for a bunch of different examples on Google and haven't been able to get anything to work as of yet.  Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: So when you click a "parent" all other parents dissapear. How do you intend to get them back again, by unclicking that one parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.parent_list > li').click(function(){
    $('ul.child_list').hide();
    $('ul.child_list', this).show();
});
```

And change your HTML to remove the extra `</li>` after "Parent1" and "Parent2":

```
<ul class='parent_list'>
    <li>
        Parent 1
        <ul class='child_list'>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Parent 2
        <ul class='child_list'>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

When the direct children of `.parent_list` are clicked, it'll hide all children lists except for it's own. I used the `.hide()` and `.show()` methods since they simply toggle the element's `display` property.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDPJ7/1/) to play around with.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/czHQE/2/

This way you won't need a `.child-list` class.

HTML:

```
<ul class='parent_list'>
    <li>Parent 1
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Javascript:

```
$('.parent_list li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().children().hide();
    $(this).children().show();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to clean up your markup also - you've closed the `<li>` tags for the "Parent 1" and "Parent 2" and then tried to close them again after the nested `<ul>`.

```
<ul class='parent_list'>
    <li>Parent 1
        <ul class='child_list'>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul class='child_list hidden'>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```